# JQuery - Couldn't update the existing name with the new name

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi actually I'm working on jQuery. Here i have written code to update my project name. for that, i have given a input field & save button. I'm getting the project name and displaying it into the input field. After editing the input field, when i click the save button, the project name is replaced with whatever name in the input field. So, here i'm facing problem when i update the value. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".detail-wrp").on("click", function() {
    let inputVal = $(".prjt-nme", this).text();
    $(".prjt-nme", this).hide();
    $(".update-wrp", this).show();
    $(".detail-input", this).val(inputVal).focus().select();
    return false;
  });
  $(".detail-save-btn").on("click", function() {
    $(".prjt-nme").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    $(".update-wrp").css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    let pk = $(this).parents(".detail-wrp").find(".detail-input").val();
    $(this).parents(".detail-wrp").find(".prjt-nme").text(pk);
  });
});
```

```css
.general-settings>div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.general-settings>div:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.general-settings>div:hover {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.general-settings>div:hover .prjt-edit-icon {
  display: block;
}

.general-settings>div>div:first-child {
  width: 40%;
}

.general-settings>div>div:last-child {
  width: 60%;
}

.general-settings>div>div .prjt-nme a {
  display: none;
}

.general-settings>div>div .prjt-nme a i {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.general-settings .update-wrp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<div class="general-settings">
  <div class="detail-wrp">
    <div>Project Name</div>
    <div>
      <div class="prjt-nme">ACTSLaw.comA1 <a href="#" class="float-right prjt-edit-icon"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></div>
      <div class="update-wrp">
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control detail-input" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="pt-1 clearfix d-flex update-and-cancel">
          <div>
            <button class="form-control detail-save-btn">Save</button>
          </div>
          <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="detail-cancel-link">Cancel</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail-wrp">
    <div>Project Name</div>
    <div>
      <div class="prjt-nme">abcdefgh.comA1 <a href="#" class="float-right prjt-edit-icon"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></div>
      <div class="update-wrp">
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control detail-input" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="pt-1 clearfix d-flex update-and-cancel">
          <div>
            <button class="form-control detail-save-btn">Save</button>
          </div>
          <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="detail-cancel-link">Cancel</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Value is updating but the input field container is not hiding.

Comment: after save, edit event is triggered again and it is showing textbox again

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Update your edit click by below:

```
    $(".prjt-nme").on("click", function() {
    let inputVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    $(".detail-input", this).val(inputVal).focus().select();
    return false;
    });
```

Moreover, you need to place project name in `<span>` and update your Save function as well to display Pencil icon again.

```
<div class="prjt-nme"><span>abcdefgh.comA1</span> <a href="#" class="float-right prjt-edit-icon"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a></div> //html 

$(this).parents(".detail-wrp").find(".prjt-nme > span").html(pk); //in save function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".update-wrp", this).show();
```

Comment this out. The .show() command will keep showing it unless you give another code to unfocus from it. You can either put in a couple of .focus to control it or better yet comment it out and test it again